# What is Ether? is it the same meaning with Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, protocol-theory

What is Ether? is it the same meaning with Ethernet?[image: Ether]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

In this context it's just an abbreviation of "ethernet".

It is of course named after the classical element "ether", also spelled "aether".  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_%28classical_element%29)